# Remove focus from a window JavaFX

Tags: javafx, focus

I'm making an onscreen keyboard with JavaFX and before i go any further, i wanted to make sure that i can un-focus the window that way the focus remains on the window that i want to send keys to.

I know that the methods `requestFocus()`, `isFocused()` exist but i need `setFocused(false)`, however, its crossed out as such.

[image]

Running the program, the window can focus and unfocus like any other window meaning that the `setFocused()` method is no longer supported?

Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Just call `requestFocus()` on the window you want to receive the focus.

Comment: well, that would work if i had a specific process in mind. but since its a keyboard, any process can use it. no?